# Why does the Preview as HTML in civimail not apply the html that has been applied to the footer

Tags: civimail, html, header-footer

Thought I was going round in circles here. Set html eg `<p><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">` to the Footer including both the Unsub token and the Domain Address token.

Preview mailing as HMTL in CiviMail. The Unsub text shows as intended, but the Domain Address shows as Times New Roman.

When I actually send a test mail, the domain address does show as sans serif. confusing.

Comment: did my below answer help? If so, please can you tick it?

Comment: hi john. to be honest I am not sure. But I have just hit a situation where clients mails were all coming through centred. Turned out, after a fair bit of head scratching, since it seems variable, that it was only being centred when the Header had a logo that was centred. If that ties in with your analysis then perhaps I should add that to your Jira issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17726

Contents in the body tag get deleted on load. When you resave they get nuked.

Comment: hi john - i  +1'd it for now. see my other comment.